# Show raid controller firmware version from Linux

Tags: centos, hardware-raid, firmware

I'm trying to find out the firmware version of my RAID controller on CentOS 7.9.

Here is my RAID controller :

```shell
# lspci -d::104 -m
02:00.0 "RAID bus controller" "Broadcom / LSI" "MegaRAID SAS-3 3108 [Invader]" -r02 "Dell" "PERC H730 Mini"
# lspci -d::104 -vv | grep -i version
        Capabilities: [50] Power Management version 3
```

I also tried browsing the `/sys/class` sub-directories but couldn't find the firmware version from Linux.

Is it possible to get this information from Linux without the need for a manufacturer's tool ?

Comment: Download storcli from broadcom site

Comment: storcli /cALL show all

Comment: https://docs.broadcom.com/docs/007.2203.0000.0000_Unified_StorCLI.zip
  https://docs.broadcom.com/doc/12352476